# How to add grid lines and implement a finer mesh in this plot?

Tags: plotting

I would like to re-create this:
[image]

I tried:

```
    ContourPlot3D[{{(
     55.00000000000001` (2.4`*^-7 + 
        3.0000000000000004`*^-7 (0.04` + \[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2)))/(-0.01` \
(0.002` \[Xi]1 + 0.012` \[Xi]2) + 
      0.00024` (0.04` + \[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2)) - z == 0}, {z == 
    1}}, {\[Xi]1, 0, 1}, {\[Xi]2, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1.5}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Blue, White}, ContourStyle -> {{Blue}, {Yellow}}, 
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

My questions:

1. How do I get a finer mesh?
2. How do I get white holes in the mesh?
3. How do I add gridlines to this plot?

Edit:

This is the updated version:

```
ContourPlot3D[{{(
     55.00000000000001` (2.4`*^-7 + 
        3.0000000000000004`*^-7 (0.04` + \[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2)))/(-0.01` \
(0.002` \[Xi]1 + 0.012` \[Xi]2) + 
      0.00024` (0.04` + \[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2)) - R0 == 0}, {R0 == 
    1}}, {\[Xi]1, 0, 1}, {\[Xi]2, 0, 1}, {R0, 0, 1.5}, 
 MeshStyle -> {White, White}, ContourStyle -> {{Blue}, {Red}}, 
 Boxed -> False, Mesh -> {40, 40, 40}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotLegends -> None, AxesLabel -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difficulty that you have encountered? And are you adding Mma code to your post soon?

Comment: @Syed yes, one minute.

Comment: @Akku14 I changed my question.

Comment: add the option `Mesh -> {40, 50, 100}` (play with the three numbers to control the number of mesh lines in x, y  and z directions) and the option `PlotTheme -> "Detailed"`.

Comment: Look at `MeshStyle -> {Blue, White}, ContourStyle -> {{Blue}, {Yellow}}` Blue contour lines on blue background are not very distinguished

Comment: @kglr this is nice, however this shifts the starting points for the axis, any fixes?

Comment: @DanielHuber thank you, I changed the mesh to white, white and contour to blue, yellow.

Comment: @kglr why is there a "breakage" in the plot between xi1from 0.5 to 0?

Comment: what do you mean by "breakage"?

Comment: @kglr its not uniform across the whole surface.

Comment: if you use `MeshStyle -> {White, Green, Yellow}`, the white mesh lines are _**equally spaced**_ in the x direction, green lines in y direction and yellow lines in z direction (for default values for the option `MeshFunctions` (which, is `{#&,#2&,#3&}`)).

Answer (score 2):

**Reply to comment**

```
ContourPlot3D[{(55.00000000000001` (2.4`*^-7 + 
         3.0000000000000004`*^-7 (0.04` + ξ1 + ξ2)))/(-0.01` \
(0.002` ξ1 + 0.012` ξ2) + 
       0.00024` (0.04` + ξ1 + ξ2)) - R0 == 0, 
  R0 == 1}, {ξ1, 0, 1}, {ξ2, 0, 1}, {R0, 0, 1.5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, MeshStyle -> {White, White}, 
 ContourStyle -> {FaceForm[Blue, White], Red}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Boxed -> False, Mesh -> {30, 30}, 
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
 PlotLegends -> None, AxesLabel -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**Original**

Here we set the `FaceGrids`,`AxesEdge`,`MeshFunctions`,`FaceForm`,`ViewPoint` and `Lighting`.

```
ContourPlot3D[{(55.00000000000001` (2.4`*^-7 + 
         3.0000000000000004`*^-7 (0.04` + ξ1 + ξ2)))/(-0.01` \
(0.002` ξ1 + 0.012` ξ2) + 
       0.00024` (0.04` + ξ1 + ξ2)) - R0 == 0, 
  R0 == 1}, {ξ1, 0, 1}, {ξ2, 0, 1}, {R0, 0, 1.5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, MeshStyle -> {White, White}, 
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint", 
 ContourStyle -> {FaceForm[Blue, White], Yellow}, Boxed -> False, 
 Mesh -> {40, 40}, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, PlotLegends -> None,
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 500, 
 ViewPoint -> {-2.24, -2.00, 1.53}]
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why below the blue mesh, the colour is silver but when I use the exact same code, its purple?

Comment: also, could you face the plot in a similar manner to the edited question? I think it looks neater/clearer. what I want is "sharp tip" of the plot on the left hand side with the neatness how your solution is presented.

Comment: @Math  I am using 12.3.1 version. Updated the answer.